# How do I stay anonymous on Twitter?

Tags: twitter

A few questions here..

I want to start following people on Twitter but I want to make sure no one can Google my name or find my OWN Twitter info. In other words I want to make sure my account remains completely private. Is this possible?

Also, I looked under the FAQ's on Twitter and it states that you can remove you phone number, name, and email from showing up but what about your actual Twitter address would that still appear in a search engine if someone knew it?

If I followed someone would they be able to see my info?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to make your account private on Twitter, so if you followed someone they can’t see your information unless they follow you back—which you have to allow.

If you want to be anonymous, I think it’s better to make a fake account with a virtual personality and make it private.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to "follow" people without them receiving any type of indication that you're interested in them is to add them to a private list:

1. Create a **private** Twitter list - `https://twitter.com/{yourUsername}/lists/`
2. Add people your'e interested in to that list
3. See what those people tweeted in the list page - `https://twitter.com/{yourUsername}/lists/{listName}`

I put quotation marks on the the word "follow" because adding people to a list is not really following them and if the list is private, these people will not recieve any type of indication what so ever that you're interested in them.